# Anyone know why my .mp4 video won't load using lightbox?

Tags: lightbox2

I am trying to use lightbox to display my video and instead of the video showing I am just getting a loading icon that never stops. I can put an image in place of the video and it works fine. Here is my code:

```
<a href="images/dawn_dause_intro.mp4" rel="lightvideo" data-lightbox="video"><img src="images/video_icon.png" height="240px" width="240px" id="middle_circle" class="circle"></a>
```

As I said, using an image in the href instead of a video works fine so the CSS and JS is linked properly. Also, the video itself loads fine without the lightbox so it's not the video's fault either.

I wasn't able to find any examples for video so I am not sure if there is something different I need to do and was unable to find the solution elsewhere, including on here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Lightbox2 doesn't support videos by default at all, and it seems the maintainer doesn't plan on adding video support either. You can always edit Lightbox2 to allow video support provided you have the Javascript/JQuery experience.

If you're using Drupal CMS, they have a custom version of Lightbox2 that supports video content. https://www.drupal.org/node/252276

Your best bet is probably finding another Lightbox that can support your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As answered above it don't supported playing Video.

But you can use some like - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ - very nice & customizable ligtbox.